# su & sudo on Mac OS X 10.9/Server 3.0

Tags: mac, sudo, su

I am trying to use su and sudo on my iMac that I did a fresh clean install of Mac OS X 10.9 and Server 3.0. I explicitly set the password for root with

```
passwd root
```

but when I try to use su or sudo from a local network account, it does not accept the password. When I was reading through some of the man pages for su, sudo and passwd, one of them (but I do not remember which) mentioned something about different behavior in an Open Directory environment. I tried digging around but could not find any more info.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

Mac uses [Open Directory Services](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_changing_your_password_passwd) to manage passwords,

The commands you want are

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist
dscl . passwd /Users/username
```

Not as easy as linux, but that is because Apple assumes passwords will usually be set through the gui.

Answer (score 0):

Is the account you trying to use `su` and `sudo` from an administrator? If not, neither will work. Also, `sudo` asks for the password of the account you are switching *from*, not the password of the account you are switching *to*. The normal way to get root access on a Mac is to use `sudo` from an admin account; since this does not require a root password, there's no reason to set one.